# iptables to isolate VM Host from vbridge

Tags: virtualization, firewall, iptables, routing, isolated-network

I ditched shorewall because it seemed overkill for the simple, unchanging ruleset this seems to call for.

I have 2 bastion firewalls in the rack between the host & each ISP.

The host contains an enclosure-bound VM which load-balances the 2 WAN connections and provides routing for multiple networks.

Since it also hosts the bridges, the VM host has an IP on each subnet that's connecting each bastion firewall to their own WAN port on the VM router.

The VM host doesn't need either of these connections other than to be able to provide the router VM access to the physical ports- the VM router provides the host's gateway & DNS.

The goal is to define rules which cause all inbound traffic on eth(n) and vmbr(n) use VM-WAN-IP-foo as a gateway, and all outbound traffic on eth(n) and vmbr(n) use bastion-fw-IP-bar as a gateway.

Also for eth(x) & vmbr(x).

---

Originally I thought I could do this with:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth(n) -s 0.0.0.0/0 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ROUTE --gw foo(n)

iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth(n) -s 0.0.0.0/0 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ROUTE --gw bar(n)
```

and

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth(x) -s 0.0.0.0/0 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ROUTE --gw foo(x)

iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth(x) -s 0.0.0.0/0 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ROUTE --gw bar(x)
```

But that didn't take, so I must not be understanding correctly what I see in the manpage.

---

When I asked in the #netfilter IRC room someone mentioned that 'ROUTE' was depreciated, and to use -mangle instead. I would have never guessed that mangling would be needed for something like this.

Am I mistaken that this should be simple & straightforward?

I have a feeling there's an easier way to go about it that I'm just not aware of, maybe someone can enlighten me.

EDIT:

To put it another way, the VM Host is hosting these connection points, but isn't allowed to use them.

It and anything else that might find it's way onto those interfaces has to go around through the VM Router to reach the VM Host.

Here's a before & after drawing of what I mean:

```
|-------|               |-------|
| ISP-A |<--|           | ISP-B |<--|
|-------|   |           |-------|   |
            |                       |
            V                       V
        |-----------|           |-----------|
        | BASTION-A |<--|       | BASTION-B |<--|
        |-----------|   |       |-----------|   |
                        |                       |
                        |                       |           
                        |                       |
         VM Host        |                       |           
            |           |                       |
            |           |                       |
           \|/          |                       |
            V           |                       |
                        |                       |           
    ||=================\|/=====================\|/==========||
    ||              |---V---|               |---V---|       ||
    ||              |       |<----\   /---->|       |       ||
    ||              |       |      \ /      |       |       ||
    ||              | eth(n)|       V       |eth(x) |       ||
    ||              |       |       |       |       |       ||
    ||              |       |<--|   |   |-->|       |       ||
    ||              |-------|   |   |   |   |-------|       ||
    ||                          |   |   |                   ||
    ||                          |   |   |                   ||
    ||                          |   |   |                   ||
    ||              |-------|   |   |   |   |-------|       ||
    ||              |       |<--|   |   |-->|       |       ||
    ||              |       |       |       |       |       ||
    ||              |vmbr(n)|       |       |vmbr(x)|       ||
    ||              |       |       |       |       |       ||
    ||          |-->|       |<--|   |   |-->|       |<--|   ||
    ||          |   |-------|   |   |   |   |-------|   |   ||
    ||          |               |   |   |               |   ||
    ||          |               |   |   |               |   ||
    ||          |               |   |   |               |   ||
    ||          |               |   |   |               |   ||
    ||          |               |   |   |               |   ||
    ||          |               |   |   |               |   ||
    ||          |              /   / \   \              |   ||
    ||          |             V   V   V   V         |---|   ||
    ||          |           |---------------|       |       ||
    ||          |           |               |       |       ||
    ||          |           |               |       |       ||
    ||          |       |-->|    VM Host    |       |       ||
    ||          |       |   |               |       |       ||
    ||          |       |   |               |       |       ||
    ||          |       |   |---------------|       |       ||
    ||          |       |                           |       ||
    ||          |       |                           |       ||
    ||          V       V                           V       ||
    ||      |-------------------------------------------|   ||
    ||      |  WAN     LAN                         WAN  |   ||
    ||      |                                           |   ||
    ||      |                     VM Router             |   ||
    ||      |                                           |   ||
    ||      |                                           |   ||
    ||      |                                           |   ||
    ||      |  LAN     LAN     LAN     LAN     SAN      |   ||
    ||      |-------------------------------------------|   ||
    ||          ^       ^       ^       ^       ^           ||
    ||          |       |       |       |       |           ||
    ||          |       |       |       |       |           ||
    ||          |       |       |       |       |           ||
    ||          ,       ,       ,       ,       ,           ||
    ||        .*^*,   .*^*,   .*^*,   .*^*,   .*^*,         ||
    ||       (     ) (     ) (     ) (     ) (     )        ||
    ||       ((    ) ((    ) ((    ) ((    ) ((    )        ||
    ||        (  .)   (  .)   (  .)   (  .)   (  .)         ||
    ||         `~      `~      `~      `~      `~           ||
    ||                                                      ||
    ||                                                      ||
    ||======================================================||











|-------|               |-------|
| ISP-A |<--|           | ISP-B |<--|
|-------|   |           |-------|   |
            |                       |
            V                       V
        |-----------|           |-----------|
        | BASTION-A |<--|       | BASTION-B |<--|
        |-----------|   |       |-----------|   |
                        |                       |
                        |                       |           
                        |                       |
         VM Host        |                       |           
            |           |                       |
            |           |                       |
           \|/          |                       |
            V           |                       |
                        |                       |           
    ||=================\|/=====================\|/==========||
    ||              |---V---|               |---V---|       ||
    ||              |       |<----\   /---->|       |       ||
    ||              |       |      \ /      |       |       ||
    ||              | eth(n)|       V       |eth(x) |       ||
    ||              |       |       |       |       |       ||
    ||              |       |<--|   |   |-->|       |       ||
    ||              |-------|   |   |   |   |-------|       ||
    ||                          |   |   |                   ||
    ||                          |   |   |                   ||
    ||                          |   |   |                   ||
    ||              |-------|   |   |   |   |-------|       ||
    ||              |       |<--|   |   |-->|       |       ||
    ||              |       |       |       |       |       ||
    ||              |vmbr(n)|       |       |vmbr(x)|       ||
    ||              |       |       |       |       |       ||
    ||          |-->|       |<--|   |   |-->|       |<--|   ||
    ||          |   |-------|   |   |   |   |-------|   |   ||
    ||          |               |   |   |               |   ||
    ||          |     //============================//  |   ||
    ||          |    //                            //   |   ||
    ||          |   //  IP Tables Says: 'Detour'  //    |   ||
    ||          |  //                            //     |   ||
    ||          | //============================//      |   ||
    ||          |              /   / \   \              |   ||
    ||          |             V   V   V   V         |---|   ||
    ||          |           |---------------|       |       ||
    ||          |           |               |       |       ||
    ||          |           |               |       |       ||
    ||          |       |-->|    VM Host    |       |       ||
    ||          |       |   |               |       |       ||
    ||          |       |   |               |       |       ||
    ||          |       |   |---------------|       |       ||
    ||          |       |                           |       ||
    ||          |       |                           |       ||
    ||          V       V                           V       ||
    ||      |-------------------------------------------|   ||
    ||      |  WAN     LAN                         WAN  |   ||
    ||      |                                           |   ||
    ||      |                     VM Router             |   ||
    ||      |                                           |   ||
    ||      |                                           |   ||
    ||      |                                           |   ||
    ||      |  LAN     LAN     LAN     LAN     SAN      |   ||
    ||      |-------------------------------------------|   ||
    ||          ^       ^       ^       ^       ^           ||
    ||          |       |       |       |       |           ||
    ||          |       |       |       |       |           ||
    ||          |       |       |       |       |           ||
    ||          ,       ,       ,       ,       ,           ||
    ||        .*^*,   .*^*,   .*^*,   .*^*,   .*^*,         ||
    ||       (     ) (     ) (     ) (     ) (     )        ||
    ||       ((    ) ((    ) ((    ) ((    ) ((    )        ||
    ||        (  .)   (  .)   (  .)   (  .)   (  .)         ||
    ||         `~      `~      `~      `~      `~           ||
    ||                                                      ||
    ||                                                      ||
    ||======================================================||
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but aren't you basically doing static NAT?  Try the SNAT target (it's in the mangle table).

Comment: SNAT doesn't look like it's going to do what I have in mind.

Comment: To clarify, I'm not looking to change any headers. Although the VM host's IP is present on the bridge, no packets are allowed to arrive there. If a packet tries to go there by means of the bastion firewall, it doesn't get rejected or dropped or allowed, but referred to the WAN IP of the VM that makes the routing decisions, located on the same bridge. Same goes for packets attempting to arrive to that IP by means of the VMs WAN port. Not drop, reject or accept, but go to the bastion instead & let it decide. Except it's all but foo & bar x & n IPs

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can actually define gateway for inbound traffic.